# MAUI Migration - Basic lifecycle/other libraries not working

Tags: xamarin.android, maui

**Background**: I have an app I am migrating from Xamarin.Android to .NET MAUI Android.

**What I've tried**: I used the VS migrator tool. I've tried manually adding some using statements for certain AndroidX libraries.

**Problem**: I am getting the following errors:

> Error CS0115  'LoginActivity.OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle)': no
> suitable method found to override (net8.0-android)
>
> Error CS0115  'LoginActivity.OnActivityResult(int, Result,
> Intent)': no suitable method found to override
>
> Error CS0115  'LoginActivity.OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem)':
> no suitable method found to override (net8.0-android)
>
> Error CS0103  The name 'FindViewById' does not exist in the current
> context (net8.0-android)
>
> Error CS0103  The name 'StartActivity' does not exist in the current
> context (net8.0-android)
>
> Error CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Intent.HasExtra(string?)'     (net8.0-android)

Some of the code these errors reference:

```
protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
txtUsername = FindViewById<EditText>(Application.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("txtUsername", "id", Application.Context.PackageName));
StartActivity(homeIntent);
clearpwd = Intent.HasExtra("clearpwd");
```

**Question**: How can I resolve these?

Where am I supposed to find information on what should be used for MAUI Android? Most documentation seems to be about cross-platform MAUI. But we are not doing that, we are doing MAUI Android (this is how Visual Studio structures it when you use the their Upgrade tool).

Answer (score 1):

You state that your app is Xamarin.Android and you have no intention of going cross-platform using Maui, yet one of your replies has `<UseMaui>True</UseMaui>` in your project file. How did you expect that to work?

My Github has multiple examples and documentation on how to convert  Xamarin.Android projects to net8.0-android. They range from converting to first net7 and then onto net8. See https://github.com/gmck. They also demonstrate modern Android practices of Single Activity apps using Android's JetPack NavigationComponent.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Xamarin.Android app and don't care about other platforms then you don't need to be concerned with MAUI. There is [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/android-projects?view=net-maui-8.0) for migrating from Xamarin.Android to .NET for Android.

It's simple enough to do manually. Just start a new CSPROJ and copy over the `<PackageReference/>` from your old CSPROJ. 95% of the old Xamarin.Android CSPROJ will be deleted.

Comment: I've gone through that article and updated my csproj file. It does have: 
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
    <UseMaui>True</UseMaui>

We are moving away from Xamarin because Microsoft is discontinuing support for it this year. We are not going to .NET Android though, too little documentation on it and it seems most organizations are moving to MAUI in some fashion.

Comment: Xamarin.Forms is discontinued. Xamarin.Android is renamed to .NET for Android and still supported. The documentation is mostly the same as Xamarin.Android with the differences highlighted in the link I provided in the answer. MAUI is built on top of Xamarin.Android/Xamarin.iOS or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: The MS documentation on this is very confusing. Here for example: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/xamarin : states " Xamarin support will end on May 1, 2024 for all Xamarin SDKs including Xamarin.Forms" - when they say all sdks including Xamarin.Forms, that implies Xamarin.Forms is just one of them, and there are others. The only others could be Xamarin.Android & Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: At the bottom of the page it says "Xamarin.Android 13 (can target SDK version 34) End of Support May 1, 2024"

Comment: @angleUr I agree it's confusing. They are just retiring the Xamarin name. It's right [there](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/xamarin#microsoft-support). "**Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Mac are now integrated directly into .NET** (starting with .NET 6) as **Android, iOS, and Mac for .NET**. If you're building with these project types today, they should be upgraded to .NET SDK-style projects for **continued support**. "

Answer (score 0):

In Maui, all projects have a `MainActivity` class(Yout project -> Platforms ->Android -> Resources -> MainActivity.cs) that derives from Activity. You can try to override `OnSaveInstanceState`, `OnActivityResult` and `OnOptionsItemSelected` in it directly.

Also, the `FindViewById` and `StartActivity` methods are available in MainActivity.

For more information about `MainActivity` in MAUI, you can refer to [Generating the manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/manifest?view=net-maui-8.0#generating-the-manifest).